# Queueing shells with CakePHP

Tags: php, shell, cakephp, queue

I'm using CakePHP 2.3.8 and I'm using the [CakePHP Queue Plugin](https://github.com/webtechnick/CakePHP-Queue-Plugin).

I'm inserting data in a queue to be processed by a shell. I can process the queue (which runs a shell), and it runs properly. However, when I process the queue the page hangs until the queue is done processing. The queue can take a while to processes because it makes external requests, and if there are failures I have some retries and waiting periods. Basically, I need to find a way to process the queue in the background so the user doesn't have to wait for it.

This is my code right now

```
App::uses('Queue', 'Queue.Lib');

//queue up the items!
foreach($queue_items as $item){

    $task_id = Queue::add("ExternalSource ".$item, 'shell');
    $this->ExternalSource->id = $item;
    $this->ExternalSource->saveField('queue_task_id', $task_id['QueueTask']['id']);

}

//now process the queue 
Queue::process(); 
echo "Done!";
```

I've also tried calling the shell directly but the same thing happens. I have to wait until it's done being processed.

Is there any way to call the shell so that the user doesn't have to wait for it to finish being processed? I'd prefer not to do it with a cronjob checking frequently.

**Edit**

I've also tried using exec but doesn't seem to be working

```
$exec = exec('/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/app/Console/cake InitiateQueueProcess');
var_dump($exec);
```

The dump shows `string '' (length=0)`. When I change exec to `exec('pwd');` it shows the directory. I can use that exact path and call the shell from the terminal so I know it's correct. I also changed the permission but still nothing happens. The shell doesn't run.

Comment: Call that Queuing function with the help of ajax request.

Comment: @Rikesh I can't say that I've ever used ajax server side (or at least realized I have). How would I do that?